# How to save a class in a entity class?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, class, datastore

I have some trouble with creating an object in an entity class. I get following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A: name.A is not a supported
>   property type

Here is a small code example:

This is my entity B class:

```
@Entity
public class B {        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    private ArrayList<A> token = new ArrayList<A>();

    public Profile() {
        this.token.add(new Token(1));
        this.token.add(new Token(2));
        this.token.add(new Token(3));
        this.token.add(new Token(4));
    }
}
```

This is my standard A class:

```
public class A {
    private Integer id = new Integer(0);

    public A(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I save the class B in the datastore. I get the exception at following point:

```
profile = new Profile();
em.persist(profile);
em.close(); //Exception
```

If I comment the token object in class B everything is working. How could I use the class A in B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that class A is not being identified as an entity to be managed. Can you use the following annotation at the top of Class A and see.

```
@Embeddable
public class A
```

Comment: Ok. If I set the class A to `@Embeddable` I get following error: `contains a persistable object that isnt persistent, but the field doesnt allow cascade-persist!` I guess, I have to set the relationship, right?. Is it OneToMany?

Comment: yes it is one-to-many. You can also put @Embedded on top of the list on your class B also. Only issue is that if you are wiring up a one-to-many, you will have to maintain a separate primary key on your Class A entity as well.